# Is there any way to set a Google Sheet to update automatically without opening the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have spreadsheets and scripts linked to it. 
But Spreadsheets need to be opened for the new data to be updated in the sheet. The same data will be used by the scripts. Currently I am facing issues since every time old data will be used by the scripts.

Comment: You can set up a time based trigger to automatically run on a time interval.  From code editor, choose "Edit" and click the "Current projects triggers" menu item.  For help, click the Help menu and choose Documentation, search for installable triggers.

Comment: You can use a [time-driven](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) installable trigger to run a function every certain time, you can create it with the [timeBased](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#timebased) method. Does this answer your question?

Comment: What data gets updated when you open the sheet? If you're talking about formula values that use `NOW`, `TODAY`, `RAND`, and `RANDBETWEEN` then you can change the spreadsheet settings to specify to recalculate those every minute/hour.